# Log in through custom jQuery dialogUI

Tags: customer, login, jquery

I'm looking for a way to leverage Magento's AccountController to allow the user to log in using a form I have created on the front page.

The user clicks a button, and can then search for the closest store, or have the option to log in.

I cant figure out how to leverage AccountController though. What I've tried is this:

```
function customerLogin()
{
    var email    = jQuery('#login-email').val();
    var password = jQuery('#login-password').val();
    jQuery.post("orderkickoff/login/login", { 'login[username]': email, 'login[password]': password } );
```

There's an HTML form on the front page where the user enters their info. This jQuery function grabs that info on the button click. It grabs the email address and the password, and then its supposed to pass it off to:

```
class Namespace_OrderKickoff_LoginController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function loginAction()
    {
        //if customer is not logged in
        if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
        {
            // get the email and load the customer by id
            $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
            $email = $login['username'];
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())->loadByEmail($email);
            $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

            //If the customer exists, log them in by forwarding to loginPost
            if($customer->getId())
            {
                // just make the customer log in
                $mysession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
                $mysession->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'));
                $mysession->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'));
                $this->_forward('loginPost','account','customer');
            }
            else
            {
                //There is no customer with that email.
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }
}
```

It seems though that my controller is not getting hit, and so its not passing off to the Magento controller to continue the sign-in process.

Is there a step I am missing?

Anyone have some good experience with using Magento's login controller?

Thanks for the input!

EDIT/UPDATE:

I think the problem is with the jQuery POST method I am using. I can navigate to the page no problem. I have WAMP environment set up so going to localhost/storeLocator/magento/index.php/orderkickoff/login/login will resolve to the correct page.

Is there a different jQuery method I should be using to pass that data?

EDIT 2:

HTML from the form

```
<div id="order-wrapper">
    <div id="inline">
        <button id="orderstart"> Start Your Order </button>
        <form id="contact" name="contact">
            <div id="deliveryops">
                Delivery <input id="delivery" type="radio" onclick="delivery" name="method" />
                Carryout <input id="carryout" type="radio" onclick="carryout" name="method" />

            </div>
            <div id="addressfordelivery">
                <br />
                <br />
                <div id="descript"> Enter the address you would like your order delivered to. </div>
                <br />
                <br />
                <input id="deliveryaddress" class="txt" type="address" name="deliveryaddress" placeholder="Address"/>
                <input id="deliverycity" class="txt" type="city" name="deliverycity" placeholder="City" />
                <input id="deliverystate" class="txt" type="state" name="deliverystate" placeholder="State"/>
                <input id="deliveryzip" class="txt" type="zip" name="deliveryzip" placeholder="Zip Code"/>
                <div id="find"> Submit </div>
            </div>
            <div id="addressforpickup">
                <br />
                <br />
                <div id="descript"> Enter your address to find our closest location</div>
                <br />
                <br />
                <input id="pickupaddress" class="txt" type="address" name="pickupaddress" placeholder="Address"/>
                <input id="pickupcity" class="txt" type="city" name="pickupcity" placeholder="City" />
                <input id="pickupstate" class="txt" type="state" name="pickupstate" placeholder="State"/>
                <input id="pickupzip" class="txt" type="zip" name="pickupzip" placeholder="Zip Code"/>
                <br />
                Search within
                <select id="pickupradius" name="pickupradius">
                    <option selected disabled hidden value=""></option>
                    <option value="5"> 5 Miles </option>
                    <option value="10"> 10 Miles </option>
                    <option value="15"> 15 Miles </option>
                    <option value="20"> 20 Miles </option>
                </select>
                <div id="lookup"> Submit </div>
            </div>

            <div id="haveaccount">

                <br />
                <br />
                ---------------- OR ----------------
                <br />
                <br />

                Have an account with us? <br /> <br />

                <input id="login-email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="text" name="login[username]" placeholder="email" />
                <input id="login-password" class="input-text required-entry" type="password" name="login[password]" placeholder="password" />
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
            <div id="signin"> Log In </div>

            <div id="display_area">
            </div>
            <div id="googlemap" style="background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden;"></div>

        </form>
```

Comment: Try debugging using chrome console or firebug for firefox (network tab). Also if your site (url in the address bar) is not https then I don't think the username/password will be submitted over ssl. I think you need to change the post action to https. Also should happen if the user is successfully log in?

Comment: Hey R.S. thanks for the input!

so watching the network tab, I can see its posting properly to index.php/orderkickoff/login and 302ing to index.php/checkout. But there is never an actual redirect. It just stays on the home page with the dialog box I've created.

Comment: Is ssl enable and is the url it posting to http or https?

Comment: Hi, try to get email and password using $this->getRequest()->getPost('email') && $this->getRequest()->getPost('password'). Btw. your code logs in customer without checking password, i can login using only email? Very dangerous.

Comment: SSL is not enabled, and it is posting to http. BUT, this is also a WAMP stack on my machine, so its not going over the internet, just my local machine. Once I migrate this to staging, then I guess I'll have to deal with SSL/https

Comment: Also add some `print_r("customer login") die();$login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login'); ...` and `print_r("customer did not log in") die(); $this->_redirect('checkout/cart'); ..` then check the network -> response tab

Comment: Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485694/magento-customer-login-programmatically

Comment: What should happen after the customer is successfully log in?

Comment: after a successful log in, it should direct the user to their account page, just like when they login using the normal account login form.

Comment: Can you include your `config.xml` - need to see how you have declared your controller resource.

Comment: Since you are using ajax (jQuery.post) the browser window will not change unless you add more code to use javascript/json to redirect on successful log in or change your code to a regular from post

Comment: `<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_OrderKickoff>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_OrderKickoff>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <orderkickoff>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Namespace_OrderKickoff</module>
                    <frontname>login</frontname>
                </args>
            </orderkickoff>
        </routers>`

Comment: OK R.S., so if I try a window.location afterwards, maybe I can get it to redirect to the proper page?

Comment: That will required more work

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll keep at this for now. Much appreciated!

Comment: Add your form html to your original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just an update!  Finally got this working after someone told me about form keys!

I changed the way the html worked to this:

```
<button id="orderstart"> Start Your Order </button>
            <form action="<?php echo $this->getURL('customer/account/loginPost'); ?>" method="post" id="contact"  name="contact">
                <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

And I had to change the submit "div" to an actual submit button

```
<button type="submit" title="Login" id="signin"> <span> Log In </span> </button>
```

The problem was in Magento 1.9 there are now "form_keys" which I guess are meant to help with XSS attacks. I was completely clueless about this, and so was banging my head against an invisible wall! Adding in that form key, and passing the data to loginPost now works!

Thanks so much for your help and your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see from your `config.xml` in the comment (better to edit your question and add it in there) you aren't even targeting your controller.  Firstly it should be `<frontName>` not `<frontname>` (I would check your entire `config.xml` against core module equivalents) and you have defined it as `login`, but you use `orderkickoff` in your URL.  The `frontName` is what links the request to the module so by using `orderkickoff/login/login` as your URL, the `orderkickoff` section is not matching against module name, or the `<orderkickoff>` node within `<routers>`, it's matching against the `frontName`.  Hence in this situation the request is not reaching your controller because there is no `frontName` match.

Correct the `frontName`, check the syntax of the rest of the `config.xml` against core references, clear at least your config cache and retry.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, thanks for the reply. I corrected this problem, and it is going to the correct controller. When I tried 

`$login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');

        Mage::log("About to dump login information");

        Mage::log($login);`

it looks like nothing is getting posted to the controller as the mage log is blank

Comment: And are values being pulled and sent with the AJAX request?

Comment: I can see in the POST XHR that the params "username" and "password" are being are being sent. Maybe they are just not in the correct format?  This is the jQuery post line I have

`jQuery.post("orderkickoff/login/login", { username: email, password: password } );`

it looks like Magento is expecting login[username] login[password]. But I cant format the post method like that

EDIT: ok, looks like if I just use a single quote I can format it like that

Comment: Well you are not going to be able to pull a `$_POST` value for `login` because you are not sending it, so logically that will be blank in the log. You can send an array as a `$_POST` value with your request, so you can build the login array and send it with the AJAX request so it hits the server as it needs to.

Comment: Actually, I just got that working. formatted the post like this: `jQuery.post("orderkickoff/login/login", { 'login[username]': email, 'login[password]': password } );`

and now when I Mage::log it, the correct information is there. It even gets so far as my `if($customer->getId())` statement, which means it SHOULD be taking over and logging me in, but it is still not. Don't know why its failing